# '__NSDictionaryI' (0x108fda238) to 'NSArray' (0x108fd9dd8). (lldb) error in get method

Tags: swift, swift3

Here is my code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    Alamofire.request("http://********************").responseJSON { (response) in
        //getting json data
        if let json  = response.result.value {

            //converting json to NSArray

            **let GiftArray : NSArray = json as! NSArray** 

            //traversing through all elements of the array

            for i in 0..<GiftArray.count {

                //adding gift values to the gift list
                self.GiftHer.append(gifther(Productname: ((GiftArray[i] ) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as? String, DescriptionData: ((GiftArray[i] ) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "description") as? String, Price: ((GiftArray[i] ) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "price") as? String, Currencytype: ((GiftArray[i] ) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "cost_currency") as? String, Companyname: ((GiftArray[i]) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "company_name") as? String, ImagesUrl: ((GiftArray[i] ) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "master_variant_images") as? String))
            }

            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }

    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

I'm converting json to nsarray then I got below error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x108fda238) to
>   'NSArray' (0x108fd9dd8).

Comment: `json` structure is key:value pairs, i.e. a `dictionary`. Why would you want to convert to a `NSArray`

Comment: i dont no ...i am new to swift ..i am following get method tutorial to display all those items in table view ..

Comment: Try replacing `NSArray` with dictionary, `[String : Any]`

Comment: yup i have tried but i am getting **Ambiguous reference to member subscript** error